# Is there any kind of archive for zone files?

Tags: dns, archiving

In the same way that [the Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org) has vast amounts of data of what websites used to look like at arbitrary timepoints, is there any analogous service that keeps track of zonefile changes?

Thankfully, I'm not asking because I've screwed up a client's zone file (which was all my friends' first question :o)  but because a site we used to run for a client has been migrated away from us and I was just curious to know when the zone file was updated to point to the new hosting provider.

Is there any way I can look at when the `A` and `CNAME` records will have changed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did anybody here post
http://dnshistory.org

Try that service

Answer (score 2):

You can find historical A records at http://viewdns.info/iphistory/ - might be of some help at least for people that face similar issues in the future?

Answer (score 1):

[http://whois.domaintools.com/](http://whois.domaintools.com)

This seems to have some archived data available for a fee.  As I can't be arsed to pay for it, I can't really tell if it's accurate or not.

It does seem to be pretty much the only thing out there, though.

Comment: It's priced rather higher than is worthwhile for my vague curiosity, but I'll bear it in mind for potential future use. Thanks, Tom!

Comment: I didn't even look at the pricing.  Just the fact there's a paywall for it put me off.  Just like online newspapers. *sadface*